# Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for AppErrorHandler: (?, [object Object]). Angular 8

Tags: angular

I am getting an error when my angular 8 app runs. The page is not getting rendered.

```
localhost/:12 GET http://localhost:4200/lib/images/logo.png 404 (Not Found)
compiler.js:2175 Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for AppErrorHandler: (?, [object Object]).
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:2175)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (compiler.js:20401)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata (compiler.js:20296)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getInjectableTypeMetadata (compiler.js:20514)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getProviderMetadata (compiler.js:20523)
    at compiler.js:20461
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getProvidersMetadata (compiler.js:20421)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (compiler.js:20148)
    at JitCompiler._loadModules (compiler.js:25824)
syntaxError @ compiler.js:2175
_getDependenciesMetadata @ compiler.js:20401
_getTypeMetadata @ compiler.js:20296
_getInjectableTypeMetadata @ compiler.js:20514
getProviderMetadata @ compiler.js:20523
(anonymous) @ compiler.js:20461
_getProvidersMetadata @ compiler.js:20421
getNgModuleMetadata @ compiler.js:20148
_loadModules @ compiler.js:25824
_compileModuleAndComponents @ compiler.js:25807
compileModuleAsync @ compiler.js:25769
compileModuleAsync @ platform-browser-dynamic.js:223
compileNgModuleFactory__PRE_R3__ @ core.js:40264
bootstrapModule @ core.js:40599
./src/main.ts @ main.ts:11
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:79
0 @ main.ts:11
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:79
checkDeferredModules @ bootstrap:45
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:32
(anonymous) @ main.js:1
```

My Code which produces this error is very simple

```
import { ErrorHandler, Inject, NgZone } from "@angular/core";
import { ToastyService } from 'ng2-toasty';
export class AppErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
    constructor(private ngZone: NgZone,
        @Inject(ToastyService) private toastyService: ToastyService) { }
    handleError(error: any): void {
        this.ngZone.run(() => {
            let errorMessage;
            if (error.message) {
                errorMessage = error.message;
            } else { errorMessage = 'Server Error !'; if (error.statusText) { errorMessage = error.statusText; } }
            console.log('->>>>>> ' + errorMessage); console.log(error); console.log('-<<<<<<');
            this.toastyService.error({
                title: 'Error', msg: errorMessage, theme: 'material', showClose: true,                //timeout: 10000                timeout: 1000000000            });        });    }

            }
```

If I comment out `private ngZone: NgZone` and its related references the app runs but I need the functionality associated so I cant remove it.

What am I doing wrong here.

Comment: You probably need to inject `ngZone` aswell.

Answer (score 2):

You should either use `@Inject` for your `ngZone` parameter

```
export class AppErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
    constructor(
        @Inject(NgZone) private ngZone: NgZone,
        @Inject(ToastyService) private toastyService: ToastyService) { }
    ...
}
```

or simply wrap your `AppErrorHandler` with `@Injectable` decorator

Answer (score 0):

The reason you got this error is becuase your class **AppErrorHandler** is initialz before Toasty Module, and when we import the **ToastyModule.Root()** in **app.module.ts** class some of the internal classes are registered as providers for dependency injection.
And **AppErrorHandler** class is initialize before Toastr Module that's why angular doesn't know how to inject the instance of toastrService in the contructor of the **AppErrorHandler**, so you need to contruct this manually. And to do that

```
export class AppErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
    constructor(
       private ngZone: NgZone,
       @Inject(ToastyService) private toastyService: ToastyService) { }

    handleError(error: any): void {
       this..ngZone.run(() => {
          -----
       });
    }
}
```